# Unsetting an item from an array in a session

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am trying to remove an item from my array in a stored session. I have attempted the following but it reverses and actually adds more!

So here is my foreach where the product shows in the cart with a button to remove from the cart:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $product) {
    $name = $product['name'];
    $id = $product['id'];
    $price = $product['price'];
    $img = $product['img'];
    $sku = $product['sku'];
    $description = $product['description'];

    echo '<a href="single_product.php?product_id=' . $product['products'] . '">';
    echo "<img src='$img'><br />";
    echo "Product: $name<br />";
    echo "Price: $price | ID: $id<br />";
    echo "$description";
    echo '</a><br /><br />';
    echo '<form action="removeItem.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="' . $product['id'] . '" />
            <button name="removeItem">Remove</button>
          </form>';    

    $sum += $price;

}
```

And here is the form to remove it but it actually adds more when you hit remove:

```
$_SESSION['products'][] = $itemid;  
$id = $_POST['id']; 

unset($_SESSION['products'][$id]);  
header("location:basket.php");
```

Comment: You're only unsetting the ID inside the single product, you probably want to unset the entire product.

Comment: that is correct yes, I am struggling to see what I am doing wrong here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$product_id = $_POST["id"];
foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $key=>$product) {
   if($product['id'] == $product_id) {
      unset($_SESSION['products'][$key]);
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: It gives me the white screen of dooooom! Sublime is flagging `unset($_SESSION['products'][$key];` as an error

Comment: There's a typo in the line you copied, it should be: unset($_SESSION['products'][$id]);

Comment: Hmm So I corrected the mistake but the item still stays in the basket...

Comment: doing a `var_dump($_POST);` gives me `array(2) { ["product_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["removeItem"]=> string(0) "" }` which is the correct id for that product

Comment: Then, you probably want to change $product_id = $_POST['id'] into $product_id = $_POST['product_id].